# Bootstrap Card Overflow

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Currently, when I use the bootstrap card the text overflows out of it like this when I reduce the height of the browser

[image]

How can I stop it from overflowing

Code

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card card-inverse card-primary" style="height: 30vh">
    <div class="card-block" style="text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;">
      <div class="display-4" style="font-size: 2rem">PERCEIVED Five (5) Year Cost of Ownership</div>
      <div class="display-3">
        {{captital | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="font-size: 50%"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example if you want us to help

Comment: Yes, im using Bootstrap 4.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `style="height: 30vh"`, or set it to `style="min-height: 30vh`". It's causing the card to overflow when it consumes more than 30% of the viewport height.

If you're using the latest 4.0.0, `card-primary`, `card-inverse` or `card-block` no longer exist. Here's the simplified card...

https://www.codeply.com/go/HCqODdTnru

```
<div class="card text-white bg-primary" style="min-height: 30vh">
     <div class="card-body text-center justify-content-center">
         <div class="display-4" style="font-size: 2rem">PERCEIVED Five (5) Year Cost of Ownership</div>
         <div class="display-3">
                        $10,000
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="font-size: 50%"></i>
         </div>
         <small class="text-light">
                 ..
         </small>
     </div>
</div>
```